# gallery borders dissapear if i set a new imageview in same activity

Tags: android, gallery, highlight, border

i have a custom gallery in android and i have i previewwindow for the items that are in the gallery.

as soon as i switch the item to be displayed in the previewindow the order around the image dissapears.

here is the on create for the activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = d.getWidth();

    // Setup window
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaperpicker);

    setupTopMenu(1, 0);

    if (width < 480) {
        findViewById(R.id.previewframe).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Init view content
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.WallpaperBrowser);
    m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,(width >= 480) ? m_previews[0] : m_bitmaps[0]);
    currentResource = 0;
    m_adapter = new BitmapAdapter(this, width);
    m_adapter.addBitmap(m_bitmap);
    for (int i = 1; i < m_bitmaps.length; ++i) 
    {
        m_adapter.addBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,(width >= 480) ? m_previews[i] : m_bitmaps[i]));
    }

    gallery.setAdapter(m_adapter);

    // Setup listeners and media scanner
    gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    Button set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetButton);
    set.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Set middle item (rounded down) in gallery as selected item
    gallery.setSelection(2);// m_adapter.getCount() >> 1, true);
    gallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false); // Change to false if image
                                            // shouldn't switch while
                                            // flinging
    gallery.onFling(null, null, 8000, 0);

}
```

and the callback when an item in the gallery is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well post an answer, seems that I didn't call:

```
((BaseAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in my `onItemSelected` function.